# PHP request data from HTTPS

Tags: php, json, httprequest

First of all, I am new in programming. I want to request specific data from another server (data from MSSQL) and transfer (insert) into my MySQL DB, what's the proper way to gain this purpose?

**PURPOSE:**

> A member from MSSQL side would like to transfer certain amount of
>   points to MySQL, member could input how much of points they had, once
>   the points is transfer into MySQL successful, a notify script would
>   send to MSSQL side for update in their end.

What should be generate on MSSQL end, so that MySQL can get these data for further processing?

For example, I have HTTPS link: `https://www.example.com/request-transfer.aspx?id=12345&sym=hello&name=linda`

For PHP processing end, how can I use cURL to get these data?

I have below script for test, isn't enough to just use $_GET?

```
// GET
$id   = $_GET['id'];
$sym  = $_GET['sym'];
$name = $_GET['name'];

$data = array("id" => $id, "sym" => $sym, "name" => $name);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/test/process.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

$input = json_decode($data_string);

echo $input->id.', '.$input->sym.', '.$input->name; 
echo $result;
```

Please advise.

Comment: can't you just open the MSSQL database to external connections? you seem to have control over that site

Comment: @Dagon, I can't control MSSQL for external use, that's why I need http request

Comment: You might want [cURL](http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php). Be aware that many providers disable/block that. Where do you run your scripts?

Comment: As I see you've already code using cURL. What is happening? What's the output? Please post error messages / log entries.

Comment: @Quasimodo's clone, I am asking about how's cURL can achieve my purpose? cause I don't see cURL is necessary, I can just use `$_GET` to gain what I want?

Comment: Can I have referral link about to use cURL for my purpose?

Comment: Sorry, the link accidentally pointed to the German version. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php is the offical PHP manual page. I've added an answer. Your code doesn't look too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks ok so far, just don't set the headers. They will be set automatically on GET/POST requests. Only on PUT requests you need to specify them.

You could JSON stringify the $_GET array directly. This would allow any parameters to be sent to the remote site. If you want to ensure only valid parameters may be sent, you have done it correct. You just should test if the GET parameter is actually present.

If you do not want repeated long expressions, you could write a short function:

```
function _GET()
{ $n = func_num_args();
  for($i = 0 ; $i<$n ;)
  { $key = func_get_arg($i++);
    $array[$key] = isset($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] : '';
  }
  return $array;
}

$data_string = json_encode(_GET('id', 'sym', 'name'));
```